# XSLT display data using string date

Tags: date, xslt, xslt-1.0

Good day everyone,

I have the following XML data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Publicity>
    <pub display="left" type="image" url="http://www.link.to.website" alt="Lorem ipsum" startDate="2010-09-01" endDate="2011-09-01">http://link.to.image/banner.gif</pub>
    <pub display="left" type="image" url="http://www.link.to.website" alt="Lorem ipsum" startDate="2010-09-01" endDate="2011-09-01">http://link.to.image/banner.gif</pub>
    <pub display="left" type="image" url="http://www.link.to.website" alt="Lorem ipsum" startDate="2010-09-01" endDate="2011-09-01">http://link.to.image/banner.gif</pub>
    <pub display="left" type="image" url="http://www.link.to.website" alt="Lorem ipsum" startDate="2010-09-01" endDate="2011-09-01">http://link.to.image/banner.gif</pub>
    <pub display="left" type="image" url="http://www.link.to.website" alt="Lorem ipsum" startDate="2010-09-01" endDate="2011-09-01">http://link.to.image/banner.gif</pub>
</Publicity>
```

I would like to display only the `pub` that are valid according to both date value `startDate` and `endDate` matched against the current date in `XSLT 1.0`.

Fyi, this XML is in a static file and is included via the `document()` function. The whole website is proceded server-side using PHP's `xsltProcessor()` function.

I hope to see PHP running a XSLT 2.0 processor natively anytime soon.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your startDate and endDate are in "YYYY-mm-dd" format, you can just strip the hyphens and do a numeric comparison:

```
<xsl:variable name="numericCurrentDate"
              select="number(translate($currentDate, '-', ''))"/>
<xsl:if test="$numericCurrentDate >= number(translate(startDate, '-', '')) and
              number(translate(endDate, '-', '')) >= $numericCurrentDate">...
```

(Thanks to http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7218.html)

Note, `translate(string, 'abcde...', '')` returns a copy of the argument string with any occurrences of the characters 'abcde...' removed.

**Alternatively**, you could use extension functions. PHP's XSLT (using libxslt) should support extensions like EXSLT's [date:difference](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html) wherever the docs say that they're implemented by libxslt... which they do in this case.

> The date:difference function returns
>   the duration between the first date
>   and the second date. If the first date
>   occurs before the second date, then
>   the result is a positive duration; if
>   it occurs after the second date, the
>   result is a negative duration.

Thus you could use:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="date:date()" />
<xsl:for-each select="...">
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(date:difference($currentDate, startDate), '-') and
                  starts-with(date:difference(endDate, $currentDate), '-')">
       Do something with publication...
```

Note that EXSLT gives us both a function to obtain the current date, so we don't have to pass it as a parameter, and a way to compare two dates.

For info on how to use the date module of EXSLT, including how to declare the namespace, see the [EXSLT docs](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html). Note, though, that EXSLT functions are not supported by all XSLT processors, so you will be sacrificing some portability.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to pass the current date in [as a parameter](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_param.asp).  Unfortunately XSLT 1.0 doesn't provide any date functions.

Comment: Yeah damn XSLT 1.0! After reading over the internet the trick would be to do some `substring` comparaison.

Comment: Hmm, how would you use substring?  If the dates are all in the same format you shouldn't need to.

Comment: I think I found the way to do it. Pseudo-code: `<xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="2010-11-08" /><xsl:for-each select="Publicity/pub"><xsl:if test="substring(@startDate, 0, 4) = substring($currentDate, 0, 4) etc..."> do something with matched pub </xsl:for-each>`